# Find integer value using bitwise logic in SQL

Tags: sql-server, bit-manipulation

I am migrating old data into a new database structure and I need to find out the total int of 3 BIT fields in SQL.

So for example,

**(Col A = 1, Col B = 2, Col C = 4**)

```
Col A, Col B, COL C
 0      0       0   = 0
 1      0       0   = 1 
 0      1       0   = 2
 0      0       1   = 4
 1      1       1   = 7
```

I have tried in SQL

```
SELECT Col A & 1, Col B & 2
```

But not entirely sure if that logic will work..

Thanks in advance

Comment: I beleive colB = 4 should be colC = 4

Comment: I advise against this. While it seems like a cool trick, it is going to use more space and also not allow indexes on the data. If the goal is to not keep adding bit columns as new true/falses are tracked, I recommend having one field whose value represents the data name and another that represents the value (So, Male and 1, or Mexican and 0, or Human and 1 could be stored within the same two columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just multiply the columns by their respective powers of 2. Assuming that `ColA` is the least significant bit:

```
SELECT ColA + ColB * 2 + ColC * 4 FROM MyTable;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e705e/1)

Comment: Thats simple to some, but not to me, hitting the binary and floating point books. thanks!